# why bin folder not exists inside wwwroot in my project?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created empty project asp.net 5 in Visual Studio 2015.

Here how it looks:

[image]

As I understand from some tutorials the bin folder have to be inside wwwroot.

But there is no **bin** inside wwwroot and also **bin** folder not exists anywhere in **Sensor Observation** project.

Any idea why bin folder not exists inside wwwroot in my project?

Comment: I suspect these tutorials refered to the root folderASP.NET 4 and earlier, not ASP.NET 5. There is no `wwwroot` folder before ASP.NET 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wwwroot` folder is from where you serve static files (e.g. css, images, JavaScript, etc.). Files in the `bin` folder should never be served to the client (e.g. browser) so it should not go in the `wwwroot` folder.

[Here is some more information](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html#the-wwwroot-folder) on what the `wwwroot` should contain. Essentially:

> "Enter the wwwroot folder in ASP.NET 5. The wwwroot folder represents
>   the actual root of the web app when running on a web server. Static
>   files, like appsettings.json, which are not located in wwwroot will
>   never be accessible, and there is no need to create special rules to
>   block access to sensitive files. Instead of blacklisting access to
>   sensitive files, a more secure whitelist approach is taken whereby
>   only those files in the wwwroot folder are accessible via web
>   requests."

Comment: But where is my bin should be?For example if I need to move files from development to production I need to move files from from bin.But I cant find bin in my project.

Comment: @Michael: You have to use `dnx publish`, then deploy the result of it to IIS and create a new application in IIS which points to the `wwwroot` folder

Comment: Please reference to the ASP.NET documentation https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html for a step-by-step guide

Answer (score 2):

The `wwwroot/bin` folder only  used to contain one single file `AspNet.Loader.dll`. The `AspNet.Loader.dll` was/is used by IIS to load the application (which resides outside of the `wwwroot` folder).

The reason for this is an increase of security. With ASP.NET Core 1.0 you don't point the application entry to the folder (that contained all the *.cs files in ASP.NET 4.5), but you point it to the `wwwroot` folder of your application.

Now IIS don't has access to the actual application files (and allow by accidental access to maybe sensitive files). So the `AspNet.Loader.dll` is required to execute your application.

Other than that, there are no other binary files in `wwwroot/bin` nor should there be any other.

**Update:**

This used to be required for Helios to be run/hosted within IIS. [Helios has been deprecated](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69) with `beta8`, because it made no sense to develop two different servers. So `wwwroot/bin` will always be empty for newer versions of ASP.NET Core. If you found posts or references, they most likely reference to an old beta.

Now Kestrel, IIS via HttpPlatformhandler (up to `rc1-final` version and [ASP.NET Core Module](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164) with rc2 and newer) and self-hosting via `HttpListener` are the supported run modes. Though one can also use Kestrel behind an IIS.